# API is an architecture, program, mechanism or what?

Tags: api

I read some of article about API, there is an article that say API is a mechanism, another article say API is set of functions and procedures, so what exactly API ?

Thank You

Comment: An API is what's provided for you to interact with a software:

* If you want to interact with a code library, the API is a set of functions, procedures and whatever else is publicly available from that library at the source code level.

* If you want to interact with a web service, the API will be the set of requests and inputs that the service accepts as well as the set of responses.

Comment: It's no different from physical interfaces such as when you want to interact with an old stereo FM receiver: the interface is all the buttons, knobs and displays that you see when you look at it. You can only interact with it through the interface.